# Can I install a Windows 8.1 app on a Windows 8 machine?

Tags: windows-8, installation, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am about to build a Windows 8.1 app for the app store.

Will users running Windows 8 be able to see my app on the app store and also will they be able to install it?

Comment: Windows 8 users will see the app and if they go to install it they'll be invited to upgrade their machine to 8.1 (free).

Answer (score 4):

to my knowledge no, you have to create a Windows 8 application for it to work on windows 8. (In windows 8.1 their are API changes that are thus not compatible with Windows 8 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263113.aspx )

However a Windows 8 application will work on Windows 8.1